# Getting access is denied for apis in Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I have provided following roles to my user though I am getting the error in the ui:

```
"Unexpected error: SupersetApiError: Forbidden":
```

Roles: [Admin, Public, Gamma]

Following are the APIs that are giving "Access is denied/Forbidden" :

```
/dynamic-plugins/api/read
/api/v1/dashboard/1
/api/v1/dashboard/1/charts
/api/v1/dashboard/1/datasets
```

Also in the below api I am getting role field as

```
/api/v1/me/roles/

API response:
{
    firstName: "test"
    isActive: false
    isAnonymous: false
    lastName: "test"
    permissions: {}
    roles: {}
    username: "test"
}
```

Can anyone please guide me what I would be missing ?

Comment: What are the permissions for Public role?